# Proxy setup question

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, squid, port-forwarding

I want to be able to access a website that is IP restricted outside the UK from my cable DSL in Germany.

A friend of mine set up a proxy server in the UK that whitelists my dedicated Debian server at a German hosting company. Since my cable DSL IP changes everyday this was the simplest setup for him.

Now, on my side I would like to set up a proxy frowarder on my dedicated Debian server to his UK proxy, in order to be able to whitelist my cable DSL IP when I need to access the particular website. I have no access to the proxy itself, apart from my Germand dedicated server's IP being whitelisted for it.

A graphic illustrates the setup:

DSL at home <------> German dedicated server <--[permitted to access]--> UK proxy <-----> UK restricted website

What tools would you recommend to set up a proxy forwarding of the UK proxy at my German dedicated server, so that my German dedicated server becomes a transparent proxy that forwards to the UK proxy? As said it is a full blown Debian system. I tried netcat port forwarding, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question here, but how about squid that you already tagged?

> client -> transparent proxy GER -> transparent proxy UK -> some site that only work for UK clients

Comment: I'm just wondering if there are other options, squid sounds fine, but probably there is something simpler?

Comment: I found this working well:

sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3128 --to-destination a.b.c.d:3128

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d a.b.c.d --dport 3128 -j SNAT --to-source w.x.y.z

a.b.c.d is the proxy, w.x.y.z is the whitelisted host